# Joomfish and phoca gallery image title character

Tags: joomla1.5, joomfish

I use Joomfish for translating phoca gallery image titles , But it shows only 15 character of image title and put ... at the end of it . 
It only limits character for image titles and other content elements of joomfish work fine . 
How can I fix it to show more character?
joomla 1.5
joomfish 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

this is because the titles are cut to fit the image box, you can change it Paramters:

**Number of Characters in Name**

http://www.phoca.cz/documents/2-phoca-gallery-component/11-global-configuration-parameters-component-in-menu-item